# SAXBuilder jdom Gives Exception

Tags: java, xml, sax, jdom

Here is the code:

```
Representation representation = representItem(exp.getItem(),MediaType.TEXT_XML);

            Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(representation.getStream());
            XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/xnat:MRSession/xnat:scan/xnat:file");
```

This gives me a InvocationTargetException error when SAXBuilder is instantiated.

Anyone have this before? Seems like this should work.

```
2012-08-07 17:17:58,441 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.restlet.XNATVirtualHost.XNATApplication - Unhandled exception or error intercepted
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder
    at org.nrg.xnat.restlet.actions.SessionCopy.<init>(SessionCopy.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.  And the xml input might help as well.

Comment: I added log, but the SAXBuilder package is in the buildpath

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that while [SAXBuilder](http://jdom.org) may be in your build path, it is not on your run path.

Comment: the jar is in my buildpath, I'm using eclipse I'm not sure I know what you mean by runpath?

Comment: Download the latest jdom.jar. If you are runnng from the same project that you build from then the dependencies should already be set up. Check in Run Configurations...->Classpath for the failing run config.

Comment: That's a pretty solid limb, methinks :)